# Can I Show A SplitViewController Using presentModalViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uisplitviewcontroller, xcode4.4

I don't know if what I'm trying to do is possible, but because I haven't the desired results, I guess not.
What I'm trying and need to do is to call a SplitViewController from a previous ViewController, using presentViewController.
I know, SplitViewController have to be the rootViewController, but I need to explore the most possible options to achieve what I need to do.
I have a MainMenu with buttons, and with every button, I need to call a SplitViewController. First, how can do this?
What I'm trying to do is this:
First, in AppDelegate I'm calling the MainMenu, and add as a subview and other things:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
   [window addSubview:self.mainMenu.view];
   [self.mainMenu presentModalViewController:self.firstMenu animated:NO]; 
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

   return YES;
}
```

Then, in the MainMenu, I'm calling SecondViewController, in modal view, using this code:

```
SecondViewController *secV = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
secV.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:secV animated:YES];
```

In this SecondViewController, I'm creating SplitViewController, with Master & DetailViewController's, using this code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

  UISplitViewController *splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc]init];

  SecondMenuViewController *secMenu = [[SecondMenuViewController alloc]init];
  UINavigationController *navLef = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
  [navLef pushViewController:secMenu animated:NO];

  SecondMainViewController *secMain = [[SecondMainViewController alloc]init];
  UINavigationController *navRig = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
  [navRig pushViewController:secMain animated:NO];

  splitViewController.delegate = secMain;
  splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navLef, navRig, nil];

  MainAppDelegate *mainApp = [[MainAppDelegate alloc]init];
  [mainApp changeRootViewController:splitViewController];

  navRig = nil;
  navLef = nil;
  secMain = nil;
  secMenu = nil;
  splitViewController = nil;
}
```

As you can see, I'm calling a method in MainAppDelegate, to change view and RootViewController, because SplitViewController have to be RootViewController. This is the method:

```
-(void)changeRootViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController{
   [self.window addSubview:splitViewController.view];
   self.window.rootViewController = splitViewController;
}
```

I know, this looks like a mess. And when I run, the SplitViewController never shows, so I assume, what I'm trying to do is not possible? Or In what I'm wrong?
If it is everything, what can I do to show a SplitViewController after my MainViewController? 
I'm using XCode4.4 and iOS5
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to make your `UISplitViewController` the root view controller in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. Then present your `MainMenu` on top of it. You can change the subviews displayed by the split view controller to correspond to what button the user pushes in your `MainMenu`.

Comment: Thank you... This option seems quick and useful. I already test it, but now I have 2 problems. The first is: in my MainMenu, I need to "store" the View, because when I need to go back, I need the MainMenu shows the last options. I tried to copy my View in another UIView before removing, and then reassign, but nothing happens, because can't copy UIView. Second problem, when I rotate the simulator, self.firstMenu does not rotate. self.firstMenu is a View with the buttons/options

Answer (score 0):

First, `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is too early to be calling `presentModalViewController`. You haven't even got an interface yet!

Second, you don't seem to have a root view controller (although perhaps you're getting one from a nib? you should probably stop doing that; use the techniques shown in the current application templates).

Third, note that now that we have custom container views, there is no need for you to use UISplitViewController at all; you can construct your own view / view controller hierarchy, and you might be happier doing so, since UISplitViewController is not a very well-constructed class.

Comment: Thank you. It sounds great to construct my own ViewController Hierarchy, pretending to be a SplitViewController, I'll try it, but I'm just a beginner, and if is complicated for my to use what is already done, do it myself is going to be a very big challenge.. Thanks for the advice

Comment: More info on how to build your own viewcontroller hierarchy in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_container_view_controllers

Comment: Thank you for share ur material